# How to determine AWS sagemaker notebook instance active time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm working on a project to retrieve information about aws sagemaker notebooks such as active time, total cost etc. For that I want to get the notebook instance up time using aws python SDK. I have tried with `boto3.sagemaker.describe_notebook_instance` but it only returns the last modified time. Is there any proper way to get this information? Thanks in advance

I have tried with `boto3.sagemaker.describe_notebook_instance` but it only returns the last modified time. using the code,
`    creation_time = response['LastModifiedTime']

```
current_time = datetime.now(creation_time.tzinfo)
up_time = (current_time - creation_time).total_seconds() / 3600`
```

I have tried to get the active time but it seems to be inaccurate.

Comment: You can maybe try to extract and send data of the notebook to cloudwatch. At the end of the day, its just a unix box... You can also see if you can use the cloudwatch agent on the instance as well... and maybe use to that to deliver system metrics .. You can then use these metrics to derive the uptimes

Comment: +1 on the comment above. Also, are you looking to find the time the instance is running, or if the users are actively running the notebook? If it's the former, use the CreateNotebookInstance and StopNotebookInstance API calls on CloudTrail. For the latter, you can use the Jupyter's last activity time (eg. https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle)

Answer (score 1):

CloudWatch logs is your best bet.

1. Go to : CloudWatch --> Log groups --> /aws/sagemaker/studio
2. Look for something like:

> > [your sagemaker studio domain id]/[sagemaker domain user name]/JupyterServer/default

> > [your sagemaker studio domain id]/[sagemaker domain user name]/KernelGateway/*

Here you will have the logs, that you can parse through and get the most accurate times.

Some messages to look out for:

1. INFO: Shutting down
2. INFO: Waiting for application shutdown.
3. INFO: Application shutdown complete.
4. INFO: Finished server process
5. [KernelGatewayApp] Kernel shutdown

Also review this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/jupyter-logs.html

And this for cost saving tips (auto shut down idle resources): https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/save-costs-by-automatically-shutting-down-idle-resources-within-amazon-sagemaker-studio/